# Cannot navigate to another screen using React navigation in React native, how to fix?

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigator

I want to navigate from one screen to another , how do i navigate ? Here is the code of my

- Required navigate to Screen
- Home screen
- stack navigator screen

`[Source code](https://pastebin.com/rmNwkTjB)`

It says cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined !
I tried fixing it , but cannot fix it , please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing navigation as props like this

```js
const Home = ({navigation}) => {
```

Use the useNavigation hook to get to the navigation object

```js
const navigation = useNavigation();





onPress={() => navigation.navigate("QR")}
```